# creating android map in intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a simple map in androi (I want to add GPS coordinates later) in intellij 9.0.1 and I installed the sdk (and android 1.1 - 2.1 sdk platform support and google api 3-7).
I created a new android project and I selected android 2.0.

Now I added  to my AndroidManifest.xml like all the tutorials say, however when I run this class it isn't found.
Does anyone know wether I'm doing something wrong or where I can find this package>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make sure that your Android facet is setup to use the Google API's.  When you configure your Android SDK from IntelliJ, you can select your build target.  I suspect you've chosen just the Android build target, and not the Goolge API build target.

Look under Project Structure->Facets->Android.  Make sure your Android Platform is one of the Google API's.

Comment: There is a problem: when  you try to add a facet, it just tells you to choose a module.  It does not present an option to choose Google API's.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve!

Once you do what Steve says, if you don't see A Google API in the platform list, you'll have to add a new platform by..

1. Clicking New
2. Browse To: /wherever_you_stored_the_android_folder/add-ons/addon_google_apis_google_inc_X (where X is the api number you want)
3. Click OK
   You should now be able to select the Google API.